# Adding camera dependency in flutter causes Exception

Tags: android, flutter

Adding this library `camera: ^0.10.5+2` into flutter project causes Exception:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
  Searched in the following locations:
   - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.2/gradle-7.4.2.pom
   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.2/gradle-7.4.2.pom
 Required by:
     project :

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

here is my `gradle` version:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
```

Comment: for every one who lives in iran, using `shecan.ir` solved my problem